# How to solve for x in $2^{2x^2}+2^{x^2 + 2x + 2} =2^{5+4x}$

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

This is the question:
$$\large{2^{2x^2}+2^{x^2 + 2x + 2} =2^{5+4x}}$$

What I did was put $~\large{2^{x^{2}}=t}$

From this, I got, roots of the quadratic:

$$\large{-2^{x+1}\pm~\left( 2^{2x+1}\sqrt{3}\right)}$$

Now this is equal to $\boxed{\large{2^{x^2}}}$. How do i find the value of x from this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The given equation can be rewritten as $$2^{2x^2-4x+2}+2^{x^2-2x+4}=2^7$$Now take $2^{(x-1)^2}=z$ which gives you the equation $$z^2+8z=2^7\implies z=8,-16$$ Taking only the positive solution gives you, (assuming $x$ to be real)$$(x-1)^2=3\implies x=1\pm \sqrt{3}$$

Comment: How did you get the intuition to do that? :o I try for so much time but cant find a way. How do you proceed in such questions?

Comment: Can i proceed with my method and get a answer?

Comment: I went for somehow removing $x^2$ and I observed that the $x$ in RHS can be absorbed in the LHS to give something of the form $(x-a)^2$. That's it. It is basically observation.

Comment: @TimKrul, I am afraid, your method does not give you a solution for $x$, since the roots themselves are in terms of the unknown $x$.

Comment: Oh i get it! We have to use such a value so that it is free of unknown x! Thanks friend!!

Comment: Yes, exactly. You're welcome Tim.